# Leitura incorreta de ponto-flutuante

Tags: c, c++

Tenho um arquivo que armazena produtos, cada produto tem três informações: seu nome (char *), quantidade em estoque (int) e seu preço (float). As informações geradas em meu programa estou salvando em um arquivo e deixando o arquivo com o seguinte formato:

```
quantidade-de-produtos
nome-produto-1
em-estoque-1 preco-1
nome-produto-2
em-estoque-2 preco-2
...
```

Exemplo:

```
1
Refrigerante Xingu
50 3.500000
```

Já que estou escrendo o arquivo, obviamente também estou fazendo sua leitura, **e é aqui que está o problema**.
Estou fazendo a leitura com o seguinte código:

```
fscanf(dados, "%d ", &quantidade);
for (struct produto p; quantidade > 0; quantidade--){
    fscanf(dados, "%[^\n]*c", p.nome);
    fscanf(dados, "%d%f", &p.EmEstoque, &p.preco);
    ...
```

Feito isso, se eu fizer a leitura no exemplo dado acima, ele irá ler corretamente todos os itens, até chegar ao preço. A leitura do preço que deveria ser 3.500000, se torna apenas 3, e o .500000 é deixado de lado e a leitura encerrada.

Qual o problema com o meu código?

Declaração de struct produto caso você precise para compreender melhor o código:

```
struct produto {
    char nome[100];
    int EmEstoque;
    float preco;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

O problema não é de leitura, é de escrita. A leitura de um float para, ao encontrar um '.', o caractere correto deve ser um ','.

Answer (score 3):

Como você não mostrou todo o seu código eu escrevi um pequeno código que lê de um arquivo de texto com a mesma formatação que o seu código lê.

file.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   FILE *fp;
   int qtd,estoque;
   char nome[100];
   float preco;

   fp = fopen("texto.txt", "r"); // read mode
   if (fp == NULL){
       perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   qtd=0;
   fscanf(fp, "%d ", &qtd);
   for (; qtd > 0; qtd--){
       fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]*c", nome);
       fscanf(fp, "%d %f", &estoque, &preco);
       printf("\n%s %d %f \n \n",nome,estoque,preco);
   }

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

texto.txt

```
1
nome
5 3.5
```

saída do programa

```
nome 5 3.500000
```

Desta forma, posso pensar que o problema no seu código deve estar numa das partes que você omitiu, vale ressaltar também que se você utilizou alguma blibioteca ou artificio para mudar a formatação do texto, ela pode requerer entradas diferentes como usar ',' ao inves do '.' para float

Comment: programas C e C++ não são chamados de "scripts", termo que normalmente só é aplicado a linguagens interpretadas tipo Python e Perl

Comment: Não tinha pensando dessa maneira, mas vou arrumar, obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, utilizar o "dot" na diretiva, no seu caso "%.2f" ao invés de ficar 3.500000 como deseja, ficaria um valor real de 3.50, sem a formatação com "dot" na diretiva, quando printar virá apenas o valor "int" do dado.

Comment: Antes de eu já fazer o post, testei isto, e não é este o problema. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Ahh beleza, ja tentou utilizar apenas a diretiva de float, no seu código escrito, está utilizando as duas em união '%d%f' fscanf(dados, "%d","%f", &p.EmEstoque, &p.preco);

Comment: Eu encontrei o erro, leia minha resposta nesta mesma pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, ainda sim, é estranho utilizar o ',' , aliás depende de alguma biblioteca que tenha incluído né, mas entendi. Rsrs até mais